# FileNotFoundException: the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, file-io, filenotfoundexception

My task is to create a program to perform statistical analysis of scores for a class of students. The class may have up to 40 students. There are five quizzes during the term. Each student is identified by a four-digit student ID number. The program is to print the student scores and calculate and print the statistics for each quiz. We are meant to use 4 different classes which are provided below

```
package lab2;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Student {
    
    private int SID;
    private int[] scores = new int[5];
    public int getSID() {
        return SID;
}

        public void setSID(int SID) {
                this.SID = SID;
        }
            public int[] getScores() {
                return scores;
            }
            public void setScores(int[] scores) {
                this.scores = scores;
            }   
            public void print() {
                System.out.println(SID + " " + Arrays.toString(scores));
            }
    }
```

```
package lab2;
import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Statistics {
        
        private int [] lowscores = new int [5];
        private int [] highscores = new int [5];
            private float [] avgscores = new float [5];
            
        void findlow(Student [] a){
            
    for (int i = 0; i < lowscores.length; ++i) {
        lowscores[i] = 100;
        for (Student student : a) {
            if (student.getScores()[i] < lowscores[i]) {
                lowscores[i] = student.getScores()[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
        void findhigh(Student [] a){
            
            for (int i = 0; i < highscores.length; ++i) {
                highscores[i] = 0;
                for (Student student : a) {
                    if (student.getScores()[i] > highscores[i]) {
                        highscores[i] = student.getScores()[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        void findavg(Student [] a) {
            for (int i = 0; i < avgscores.length; ++i) {
                avgscores[i] = 0;
                for (Student student : a) {
                    avgscores[i] += student.getScores()[i];
                }
                avgscores[i] /= a.length;
            }
        }
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("High Score " + Arrays.toString(highscores));
            System.out.println("Low Score " + Arrays.toString(lowscores));
            System.out.println("Average " + Arrays.toString(avgscores));
        }
    }
```

```
package lab2;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Util {

   public static Student[] readFile(String StudentScores, Student[] stu) {
     
        int i = 0;

        //Reads the file and builds student array.
        try { FileReader File = new FileReader(StudentScores);
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(File);

            // skipping header row
            boolean eof = buff.readLine() == null;

            while (!eof) {
                String line = buff.readLine();

                if (line == null)
                    eof = true;

                else {
                    String[] data = line.split(" ");
                    stu[i] = new Student();
                    stu[i].setSID(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));

                    int[] scores = new int[data.length - 1];

                    for (int j = 1; j < data.length; ++j) {
                        scores[j - 1] = Integer.parseInt(data[j]);
                    }
                    stu[i].setScores(scores);
                    ++i;
                }
            }

            buff.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error -- " + e.toString());
        }

        Student[] students = new Student[i];
        System.arraycopy(stu, 0, students, 0, i);
        return students;
    }
}
```

```
package lab2;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Driver {
    
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
    
     Student[] lab2 = new Student[40];
     // Populate the student array
     lab2 = Util.readFile("filename.txt", lab2);
     Statistics statlab2 = new Statistics();
     statlab2.findlow(lab2);
     statlab2.findhigh(lab2);
     statlab2.findavg(lab2);
     System.out.println("Stud Qu1 Qu2 Qu3 Qu4 Qu5");
     for (Student student : lab2) {
     student.print();
     }
     statlab2.print();
     }
    }
```

The input is supposed to be read from a text file. I have a file named `StudentScores.txt` but when I try to run it I get this message. I'm not sure where to go from here or how to resolve this issue. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error -- java.io.FileNotFoundException: StudentScores.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
Stud Qu1 Qu2 Qu3 Qu4 Qu5
High Score [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Low Score [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
Average  [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

`

Comment: It could be the problem with the file location. Have you checked your file location? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Answer (score 0):

From the error:
`Error -- java.io.FileNotFoundException: StudentScores.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)`

It states that the targeted file is not being read.

From the below code, it tries to read the file **filename.txt**:

```java
lab2 = Util.readFile("filename.txt", lab2);
```

You have to ensure that there is a file named **filename.txt** in your working directory, or in the same directory with your executable.

Or you can always try to replace `filename.txt` with the exact path to your **filename.txt** first.

```java
lab2 = Util.readFile("C:/.../.../filename.txt", lab2);
```